# how to push the form data into array while clicking the submit in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Here I have form data. I have to push that data into an array. And the same time I have to retrieve that data and will show in another component.

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';
import DisplayOutput from '../pages/DisplayOutput';
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

class DialogFormWithFormik extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      userName: '',
      password: '',
      data:'',
      dialogModal: 'none',
    }
  }

  handleClickOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true })
    this.setState({ dialogModal: 'login' })
  }
  handleRegisterClickOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true })
    this.setState({ dialogModal: 'register' })
  }

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ dialogModal: false })
  }
  handleUsernameChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      userName: event.target.value,
    })
  }
  handlePasswordChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      password: e.target.value,
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(this.state.userName + '' + this.state.password)
    alert('values submitted')
  }

  form = props => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          variant="outlined"
          color="primary"
          onClick={() => this.handleClickOpen()}
        >
          Login
        </Button>
        &nbsp;
        <Button
          variant="outlined"
          color="primary"
          onClick={() => this.handleRegisterClickOpen()}
        >
          Register
        </Button>
        <Dialog
          onClose={() => this.handleClose()}
          aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
          open={this.state.dialogModal === 'login'}
        >
          <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">
              To Display Student Data
            </DialogTitle>
            <TextField
              label="Username"
              type="text"
              margin="normal"
              name="userName"
              id="userName"
              onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}
              value={this.state.userName}
            />

            <br />
            <TextField
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              autoComplete="current-password"
              margin="normal"
              id="passsword"
              onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
              value={this.state.password}
            />
            <br />

            <DialogActions>
              <nav>
                <Button variant="contained" type="submit" color="primary">
                  Login
                </Button>
              </nav>

              <br />
              <Button onClick={() => this.handleClose()}>Cancel</Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </Form>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    )
  }
  schema = () => {
    const schema = Yup.object().shape({
      userName: Yup.string().required(),
      password: Yup.string().required(),
    })
    return schema
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Sample" align="center">
        <Formik render={this.form} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default DialogFormWithFormik
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method that handles the submit of the form, have the event as a parameter and call `preventDefault` [Read more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).
So the page doesn't reload when submitting. And then push the the data to the correct array.

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually, my question was, when I will submit the form, the form values I should have to store in one array(like JSON). here I have to create one array object. after that, I have to retrieve the data from an array. can I display that array values in another component

Comment: I would use Redux/MobX/React Context for data-transport (in lack of a better word).
[React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
[Redux](https://redux.js.org/)
[MobX](https://mobx.js.org/)

Comment: If i will use e.preventDefault(). the values are still in that field only. if we will clear the field data then only values are clear. but I don't want that. I want form should be there with the empty fields. and one thing. please read my first comment. I want to the solution for the above question.

Comment: If you would like the fields to be empty after the submit, you should have trigger a method that resets state-data after the submitting.

Comment: How can I save the form data(like userName and password) into an array?

Comment: `users.push({
  userName: userName,
  password: password
});
`

Comment: if u don't mind how can I approach that? can you explain in code

Comment: when I am creating a Gatsby project. I am getting this error this error‼ 
  ‼ pngquant pre-build test failed
  I compiling from source
  × Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pngquant-bin@5.0.1 post-install: `node lib/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pngquant-bin@5.0.1 post-install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
error Command failed: npm install
  Error: Command failed: npm install

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I create for only one input field, and  import and export  your component  as per your project file

```jsx
state = {
  username: '',
  items:[]
};

handleFormSubmit = (e) => {

  e.preventDefault();
  let items = [...this.state.items];
  items.push({
    username: this.state.username
  });
  this.setState({
    items,
    username: '',
  });
};

handleInputChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    username: e.target.value
  })
}

render() {

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <form className='from-group ' onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>

          <input className='form-control no-border input-field ' id="username" value={this.state.username} type="text" name="username" onChange={this.handleInputChange} required/>

          <div className="text-center">
            <button type='submit' className="mt-3 col-md-12 btn  btn-primary">ADD</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div className='mt-3'>
          <div className='center'>
            <table className="table table-dark table-hover">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>Username</th>
                </tr>
                {this.items.map(item =>{ 
                return(
                  <tr>
                    <td>{item.username}</td>
                  </tr>
                  ); 
                })}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
};
```